# How to connect to database using z39.50

Tags: python, z39.50

```
from PyZ3950 import zoom
conn = zoom.Connection ('z3950.iacentre.com', 210,user='gaurishankar')
conn.databaseName = 'itke'
conn.preferredRecordSyntax = 'USMARC'
query = zoom.Query ('CCL', 'mango')
res = conn.search (query)
print res [0]
```

This is my code and I am not able to make connection with database.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: disconnected: Graceful close

Comment: '00626nam a2200193 a 4500001001000000003000600010005001700016008004100033020001500074092001600089100002400105245009300129260002800222300002800250490001900278650004300297650004200340852005000382\x1e010000187\x1eUkOxU\x1e19960506171756.0\x1e880921s1988    enk           000 0 eng u\x1e  \x1fa1850761213\x1e  \x1faD0000006377\x1e10\x1faChant, Christopher.\x1e10\x1faAviation record breakers :\x1fbinnovations in modern flight technology /\x1fcChristopher Chant\x1e  \x1faLondon :\x1fbApple,\x1fcc1988\x1e  \x1fa127 p. :\x1fbill. ;\x1fc29 cm\x1e0 \x1faA Quintet book\x1e 0\x1faAeronautics\x1fxT

Comment: This is data I am getting how to convert in XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer

```
from PyZ3950 import zoom
conn = zoom.Connection ('z3950.iacentre.com', 210,user='gaurishankar')
conn.databaseName = 'itke'
conn.preferredRecordSyntax = 'USMARC'
query = zoom.Query ('CCL', 'mango')
res = conn.search (query)
for i in res:
    print i,i.data
```